# Replacement for attribute binding syntax in Ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js

Previously I could do something like this to get a two-way binding to a dynamic key:

```
{{my-component idBinding='content.dynamicKey'}}
```

In Ember 2.0 this generates a depcrecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION: You're using legacy binding syntax: idBinding=content.dynamicKey 
Please replace with id=content.dynamicKey
```

Unfortunately I cannot bind to content.dynamicKey as this will only bind to the string value and not the actual path mapping to the value.

How can I achieve the above behaviour in Ember 2.0?

Comment: `{{my-component id=content.dynamicKey}}` didn't work?

Comment: nope. doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just `{{my-component id=content.dynamicKey}}`.

Possible duplicate of [Input helper valueBinding is deprecated - what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395693/input-helper-valuebinding-is-deprecated-whats-the-alternative/29396502#29396502)